# Paginacion en php

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes estoy trabajando actualmente en mi proyecto y me he topado con un error en la paginación al consultar unos datos de una tabla con php. El punto es que no logro detectar el error ya que en la primera consulta me aparece la información, pero cuando cambio de pagina me arroja error en los index, si alguien me puede ayudar mucho lo sabría agradecer.
PD: Como verán solo aplique la paginación al primer if ya que estaba haciendo las pruebas.
PD2: les dejo las capturas para que observen que si consulta y que luego me arroja el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listado de Alumnos</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php

 $Conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba2") or die ("Problemas en la conexion");

    if ($_REQUEST['radio1'] == "Cedula") 

 {
    $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by CedulaAlumno  limit $inicio,5") or die 
                             ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));


    $impresos=0;
    while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

    {
    $impresos++;
    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
    echo "<hr>";
    }

            if ($inicio==0)
            echo "anteriores ";
            else
            {
              $anterior=$inicio-5;
              echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$anterior\">Anteriores </a>";
            }
            if ($impresos==5)
            {
              $proximo=$inicio+5;
              echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$proximo\">Siguientes</a>";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "siguientes";
            }

  }


  elseif ($_REQUEST['radio1'] == "Seccion") 


 {
  $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by Seccion") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

    while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

    {

    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
    echo "<hr>";    
    }
   }


    elseif ($_REQUEST['radio1'] == "Apellidos") 

   {
$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by PrimerApellidoAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

    while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

    {

    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
    echo "<hr>";
    }
   }


     elseif ($_REQUEST['radio1'] == "Nombres") 


    {
$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by PrimerNombreAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

    while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

    {

    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
    echo "<hr>";
    }
   }


    elseif ($_REQUEST['radio1'] == "Edad") 


    {
$Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by EdadAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

    while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

    {

    echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
    echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
    echo "<hr>";
    }
   }
   mysqli_close($Conexion);
  ?>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el fallo viene en la orden $_Request, ya que al recargar con los registros, recargas la página, perdiendo esta variable.

Prueba a modificar el JS con este código

```
if ($inicio==0)
        echo "anteriores ";
        else
        {
          $anterior=$inicio-5;
          echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$anterior&radio1=$_REQUEST['radio1'] \">Anteriores </a>";
        }
        if ($impresos==5)
        {
          $proximo=$inicio+5;
          echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$proximo&radio1=$_REQUEST['radio1']">Siguientes</a>";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "siguientes";
        }
```

Comment: Buenas noches, muchas gracias, después de acomodar unas comillas corrió, pero ahora no arroja los errores, la pantalla queda en blanco.

Comment: Revisa esta página  https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2015/12/25/paginacion-con-php-y-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esa manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Listado de Alumnos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

     $Conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba2") or die ("Problemas en la conexion");

        if (isset($_REQUEST['radio1']) == "Cedula") 

     {
        $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by CedulaAlumno  limit $inicio,5") or die 
                                 ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));


        $impresos=0;
        while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

        {
        $impresos++;
        echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
        echo "<hr>";
        }

                if ($inicio==0)
                echo "anteriores ";
                else
                {
                  $anterior=$inicio-5;
                  echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$anterior\">Anteriores </a>";
                }
                if ($impresos==5)
                {
                  $proximo=$inicio+5;
                  echo "<a href=\"Listados_Alumnos_Servidor.php?pos=$proximo\">Siguientes</a>";
                }
                else
                {
                  echo "siguientes";
                }

      }


      elseif (isset($_REQUEST['radio1']) == "Seccion") 


     {
      $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by Seccion") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

        while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

        {

        echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
        echo "<hr>";    
        }
       }


        elseif (isset($_REQUEST['radio1']) == "Apellidos") 

       {
    $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by PrimerApellidoAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

        while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

        {

        echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
        echo "<hr>";
        }
       }


         elseif (isset($_REQUEST['radio1']) == "Nombres") 


        {
    $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by PrimerNombreAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

        while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

        {

        echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
        echo "<hr>";
        }
       }


        elseif (isset($_REQUEST['radio1']) == "Edad") 


        {
    $Registros = mysqli_query($Conexion, "select * from alumnos order by EdadAlumno") or die ("Problemas en el select: ".mysqli_error($Conexion));

        while ($Reg = mysqli_fetch_array($Registros)) 

        {

        echo "Cedula del Alumno: ".$Reg['TipoCedulaAlumno']." ".$Reg['CedulaAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Apellidos del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerApellidoAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoApellidoAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Nombres del Alumno: ".$Reg['PrimerNombreAlumno']." ".$Reg['SegundoNombreAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Edad: ".$Reg['EdadAlumno']."<br>";
        echo "Seccion: ".$Reg['Seccion'];
        echo "<hr>";
        }
       }
       mysqli_close($Conexion);
      ?>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes intentar algo usando variables de sesion para que no se te pierda la variable, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
session_start();
$_REQUEST['radio1']=isset($_SESSION["radio1"])?$_SESSION["radio1"]:$_REQUEST['radio1'];
$_SESSION["radio1"]=$_REQUEST['radio1'];
```